# Получить ID объекта по его нажатию в TWebBrowser

Tags: webbrowser, delphi, delphi-7

Прива всем ... 
Есть вопрос ... вообще это тривиальноу, ну ... выполнимо ?
Вообщем так:

Загружаем через wb1 страницу, допустим google.ru, нажимаем по полю ввода и Label1.Caption:=id этого поля.

Спасибо за любые нормальные советы !

Answer (score 3):

Гуууууугль!

```
procedure TForm1.MyMessages(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
 var
   X, Y: Integer;
   document, E: OleVariant;
 begin
   Handled := False;
   if (WebBrowser1 = nil) or (Msg.message <> WM_LBUTTONDOWN) then
     Exit;

   Handled := IsDialogMessage(WebBrowser1.Handle, Msg);

   if (Handled) then
   begin

     case (Msg.message) of
       WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
         begin
           X := LOWORD(Msg.lParam);
           Y := HIWORD(Msg.lParam);
           document := WebBrowser1.document;
           E := document.elementFromPoint(X, Y);
           Label1.Caption:=E.id;
         end;

     end;
   end;
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage := MyMessages;
end;
```

Comment: [Delphi - OnClick для TWebBrowser](http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread25897.html)